# How can I customize what GET returns

Tags: json, asp.net-core, http-get

I want my API to return a custom text before the JSON that it returns. Now it only returns JSON but how can I show another static text before JSON.

Let's say my GET returns me this `[{"name":"name"...}]` I want to return `StaticText [{"name":"name"...}] StaticText"`

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Customers>>> GetCustomers()
{
   return await _context.Customers.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add a custom header? You only have one "main" response. You can combine your actual response and your static text into a JSON object holding both information. Would that work for you?

Comment: @citronas My question might be so dumb but I'm new to this staff so I edited my question may be it is more clear

Comment: Why don't you just change the method result?

Comment: @ilkerkaran I don't know what should I use for this

Comment: @lunarfry Assumed you just want to modify this method's result and added an answer. If you want to add the static tet to every get method result you will need another approach

Comment: @ilkerkaran I only need for getting all so this should be enough thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to stringify your result then concatenate the string you want;

```cs
...
var yourCustomStr = "I am a custom string!";
var result = await _context.Customers.ToListAsync();
var resultStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
return Content($"{resultStr} {yourCustomStr}", "application/json");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment and your edit, you can create a class which wraps your result and your static text:

```
public class MyResult
{
    public IEnumerable<Customers> Customers {get; set;}
    public string StaticText {get; set;}
}
```

Change your controller code like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<MyResult>> GetCustomers()
{
    var list = await _context.Customers.ToListAsync();
    return new MyResult()
    {
        Customers = list,
        StaticText = "my static text"
    };
}
```

Comment: I think OP does not want the static text in { } . That's why I added another answer. Happy coding!

Comment: @ilkerkaran Is that valid JSON? Shouldn't it be in an array?

Comment: @citronas Yeah what I want was the second answer but thanks for help anyway. I learned another thing :)

Comment: @citronas actually no, it is not a valid JSON string. I just tried to generate what OP wanted. I am pretty sure this is kinda x,y problem. But I am happy as long as Op is happy =)